# Passing Enum value in a method from dropdown?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, enums

I need to call a method from a webservice, which expects parameter as enum.

There are two parts of my Question:

1) How to bind the drop with enum values?

2) How to pass selected value from drop down to webservice method as enum type?

Can somebody help me in this?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have ans of you first question

```
enum enCountries:int{India=0,USA,UK,UAE};// Declare Enum

var enumNames=Enum.GetNames(typeof(enCountries)); //convert into string array
foreach (string item in enumNames)
{
//get the enum item value
int value = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(enCountries), item);
ListItem listItem = new ListItem(item, value.ToString());
dropdown.Items.Add(listItem); // bind dropdown
}
```

selected value of dropdown always gives you  single values so  Why you want to convert single value to enum..???

for your second question  first create an Enum

```
  Enum EnumName{}
  Enum.Parse(typeof(EnumName), Dropdownselectedvalue, true); //this will convert you selected value to EnumName Type
```

Comment: First of all I am getting enum list from webservice so i dont know the type, second i need to load enum list into drop down then pass the selected value of dropdown to the webservice method.